# Eigen: How to check if Matrix is invertible

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I would like to generate a random invertible Matrix using Eigen, which fulfills these criteria:

```
Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> res(M, N + 1);
Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y(M, 1);
y.setRandom();
while (true) {
    res.setRandom();
    Eigen::FullPivLU<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> lu(res.transpose() * res);
    if (lu.isInvertible()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

So `res^T*res` should be invertible, but i need a random `res`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: How is that supposed to help? @JesperJuhl

Comment: You want a random "something". That link tells you how we generate random numbers in modern C++. So it's supposed to help by showing you how to generate random numbers so you can generate your random thing.

Comment: Changed the comment, now it should reflect my question better

Comment: Your actual question is "How to create random, full-ranked, symmetric positive-definite matrices?" (Or random, full-ranked, `Mx(N+1)` matrices?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check isInvertible should work here. For a diagnostic, you can check the absolute value of the determinant or the condition number of your matrix. You should be able to use the determinant member function, see: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a7ad8f77004bb956b603bb43fd2e3c061

Comment: is that faster or slower than what i did here?

Comment: It should be similar, the technique used for both is LU decomposition. In your problem though, matrices with random double ("real") coefficients will be of full rank with probability 1 so the product will be invertible (a.s.) as long as N+1 is less than or equal to M.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. Problem is though, when i set those matrices without checking, i often got runtime erros, because the matrices where singular ... i forgot to mention, that col 1 will always be 1 in res

Comment: I think your problem might be when you are assigning the random entries,try using res.setRandom(M,N+1) to explicitly use the matrix random setter. For debugging, try choosing a small enough M and N that you can debug res manually; verify that all the columns are linearly independent.

Comment: Checking the determinant to determine if a matrix is invertible is usually a bad idea, since the determinant scales dramatically. E.g., if `det(A)==1`, then `det(s*A)==pow(s,A.rows())`. Checking with `.isInvertible()` is much better (but I don't think that is the actual problem of the OP)

Comment: @chtz edited my answer. I suspect in this case det will still be small, at least compared with what you would expect from a matrix X^TX, X random (abs(det) will be around const(N^N) with high probability).